# Error handling between button and bean method

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I have a jsf button that calls a bean method called generateLicense. This bean method returns a string to perform a redirect, like this

```
"/licenseGenerated.xhtml?faces-redirect=true"
```

This method is supposed to do several back-end calls based on the user's input. Now, this means that in I have to add some error handling. Here's the behavior I need.

The user accesses the application and is in the main.xhtml page. The user inputs the value and clicks the button. If the whole procedure works correctly, then the user should be redirected to the /licenseGenerated.xhtml page. Otherwise, in case an error happened, I don't need a redirect. What I need is to render a jsf component that contains an error message on the main.xhtml page.

So, what should the generateLicense method return in case of an error, and what would the button's jsf code be like?

Thanks for the help!

-EDIT-

The error would be detected during the bean's method execution. This is based on a response from a rest service. Simply said, there are two possible outcomes from the service. A 200 (OK), in which case, the redirect is needed, or a 400 (NOT FOUND) in case the user's input is wrong. So, the java method would look like this:

```
public String generateLicenseFile(){
   String response = ""; 
   ... // all the back-end computations
   if(response == "200"){
       return "/licenseGenerated.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";
   }else{
       //ERROR HANDLING. 
   }
}
```

This is the button's current code.

```
<h:commandButton value="Generate License File" action="#{agreement.generateLicenseFile}" />
```

Comment: What exactly is it, the "an error" which you're talking about? JSF validation error like `required="true"`? That would be quite strange as the JSF action is by default not performed on a conversion/validation error and thus you shouldn't be worrying about this at all.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't specify much. I'll add more info in the post with an edit. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a faces message and return `null`.

```
} else {
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(
        FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Sorry, generating license file has failed. Please try again later.", null));
    return null;
}
```

The [`FacesContext#addMessage()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/FacesContext.html#addMessage%28java.lang.String,%20javax.faces.application.FacesMessage%29) call on a `null` client ID will make it a so-called global message which you can filter out with [`<h:messages>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/h/messages.html) as follows:

```
<h:messages globalOnly="true" />
```

Returning `null` would make it to return to the same view as where this action is been invoked from.

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, the `if (response == "200")` really doesn't do what you think it does. I suggest to spend a bit more time learning basic Java.

Comment: Thanks! The code itself is a lot more complex, so I tried to give a very, VERY general idea of what it's supposed to do. I still appreciate your help and concern.

Comment: You're welcome. General or not, comparing string values with `==` is still fundamentally wrong.

Comment: Got it. Also, one last thing. This solution does exactly what you say, but on error, I have to render a component that says an error message. I think I can use valueListener, so I'll also try that. Thanks!

Comment: Just use `<h:messages>` as answered. It will show up when there's a message.